# How to simply encrypt a string with OpenPGP.js?

Tags: javascript, encryption, public-key-encryption, openpgp

I just want to be able to do something like this:

```
function encryptString(string, publicKey) {
    // do stuff....
    return encryptedString;
}
```

I had a look at OpenPGP and JSEncrypt. JSEncrypt doesn't seem to work at all. Just returns false. And OpenPHP requires asynchronous calls when I need a realtime synchronous calculation.

Any thoughts as to what I could be doing wrong?

For JSEncrypt, the false I am getting is most likely due to my key being very long. This library seems to support short strings.

Im a bit lost. Any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated?

Comment: Those APIs are asynchronous for a reason. Computation, particularly asymmetric encryption, is usually compute heavy and you don't want to hang the main thread for too long. Web Crypto API also provides only an asynchronous version, so many crypto libraries will use that under the hood. Though, I haven't checked for OpenPGP.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me (although it's certainly not elegant):

```
function pgp_encryptValues(cvv, cc)
{
    var keyId = '{{ $keyId }}';
    var base64EncodedPublicKey = '{{ $publicKey }}';

    var CardDetails = {
        "number": cc,
        "cvv"   : cvv
       };
       const stringified      =  JSON.stringify(CardDetails);
       const pciEncryptionKey = base64EncodedPublicKey;
       const decodedPublicKey = atob(pciEncryptionKey)

        async function setPgpCode()
        {
            const options = {
             message: openpgp.message.fromText(stringified),
                publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(decodedPublicKey)).keys
            }
            return openpgp.encrypt(options).then((ciphertext) =>
            {
                var cipherResultEncoded = btoa(ciphertext.data);
                jQuery("#encryptedData").val(cipherResultEncoded);
                jQuery("#keyID").val(keyId);
                return {
                    encryptedData: btoa(ciphertext.data),
                    keyId: keyId
                }
            })
        };

        if (promiseStarted) {
            while (promiseStarted)
            {
                // wait til its done...
            }
        }

        promiseStarted   = true;
        promiseEnded     = false;
        setPgpCode();
        promiseStarted   = false;
        promiseEnded     = true;

    }
```

Very hackey and I'll probably improve it over time, but at least it works!